# Common layouts for modular app

Tags: phalcon, volt

I write modular app and want common path (Volt layouts) for all modules.

```
$view->setLayoutsDir(PATH_APP . '/common/layouts/'); // don't solved problem

{% extends "../../../common/layouts/base.volt" %} // so ugly

{% extends common_layouts ~ "base.volt" %} /* return error 
"Syntax error, unexpected token IDENTIFIER(common_layouts)..." */
```

P.S.: not forgotten about:

```
$view->setVar('common_layouts', PATH_APP . '/common/layouts/');`
```

Do u have solution?

Answer (score 1):

look here for [backup view path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20030947/2273046) - I think that might help in your situation.

You will need to use just `"default.volt"` instead of realtive paths.

Btw, in your 3rd solution you can use `{{ partial(comm_layouts ~ 'base.volt') }}`.